FLRW: GR meets QM, coincidence or deeper connection?
If we assume a closed FLRW universe that begins with exponential inflation caused by dark energy style constant density, the Hubble parameter in this epoch would be
$$\rm H=H_0\sqrt{\Omega_{\Lambda}+\frac{1-\Omega_{\Lambda}}{a^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{8 \pi G \rho_{\Lambda}}{3}-\frac{k c^2}{a^2}}$$
where $\rm H=0$ when $\rm a=\sqrt{1-1/\Omega_{\Lambda}}$, so such a universe would start off static and then expand rapidly (in the beginning $\rm H \propto t$, which then converges to a constant value).
If I take the intial density $\rm \rho_{\Lambda}$ to be the Planck density, I also get one Planck length as the maximal initial distance between two points in the beginning when $\rm H=0$, where the maximal distance in such a closed universe would be the half curvature circumference $\rm r_k \pi $ with the curvature radius $\rm r_k=1/\sqrt{k}$ and $\rm k=8 \pi G \rho_{\Lambda}/(3 c^2)$.
Now I wonder why the FLRW, which is pure relativity, coincides that way with quantum mechanics, since the Planck constant from which the Planck density and Planck length are derived have no play in relativity.
Is it a coincidence that the Planck density requires the Planck length as the maximal initial distance between two points in a closed inflationary universe, or am I overlooking something?

It seems to me you are only getting the Planck length out because you are putting the Planck density in, or am I missing something? That is, you get $r\propto \hbar^{1/2}$ because you set $\rho\propto \hbar^{-1}$ and evaluate $r\propto\rho^{-1/2}$.

@Sten - Sure, but the radius to density relation in this scenario is pure GR, so it is not a given that that the Planck length pops out if I put the Planck density in.

The Planck units are all closely related and the operations you’re performing aren’t specifically unique to GR; like Sten said it makes sense that you get one Planck unit from another with elementary operations. I personally wouldn’t be surprised.
